# Hive Managed table getting "java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bucketId out of range: -1 (state=,code=0)"

Tags: hive

I have created Hive Managed Table with ORC and PARQUET format. While getting the values from table with "Select * from table_name" I am getting below error.

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bucketId out of range: -1 (state=,code=0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the DDL of the table. Table seems to be a bucketed table. However, the underlying folders/files are of different bucket sizes compared to the table definition.

Comment: It is simple table without any partitioning and bucketing property.